# VB 2019 startup object default

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to change VB 2019 startup object  DEFAULT from sub main to Form1? I'm a high school CS teacher switching from VB 2015 to 2019. My kids are entirely new to programming. I don't want them to have to go into Project settings to change the start up object every time they create a new program.

Comment: Are you selecting Windows Forms project or Console Application?

Comment: Totally off topic but given any choice I would teach them c# instead of VB having both taught and professionally programmed using both those and it is much easier to teach good practices using c# IMHO

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Having used both professionally, I think VB is fine as long as you force `Option Strict On`.  The main issues come from the things that VB will let slide when you don't have that option set.  (I'm obviously setting aside the relative professional utility of the two languages... there's a lot of VB out there, but no question that C# is by far the more prevalent language.)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss.  Sorry but this is such an out dated way of thinking.  As long as correct principles, practices and concepts are taught, the language doesn't matter as that will all translate.  Especially when your proposing C# over VB which at the most basic level, the only difference is syntax.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss vb.net is easier to teach because it has more readable words. Introducing students to brackets, braces and semicolons it more confusing and harder to type. Too many typing errors only frustrates students and gets in the way of teaching the concepts. It is easy enough to switch once concepts are taught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have created a Windows Forms project that is targeting .NET 5. That will default to `Sub Main` as the startup object. .NET 5 is the latest and greatest but it is based on .NET Core rather than .NET Framework. As a result, there will be a number of subtle differences and a few things missing in relation to your coursework, which would have been written based on .NET Framework. Especially for beginners, I strongly recommend sticking with .NET Framework for Windows Forms apps for the time being.

In the *New Project* dialogue, all the project templates that target .NET Framework specifically say so. When you create a new Windows Forms project, be sure to select the template named **"Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)"** rather than the one named **"Windows Forms App"**. The former will enable you to target .NET Framework 4.8 and earlier. That will behave exactly as you're used to from VS 2015. It's a good idea to type "framework" into the filter box on the *New Project* dialogue to be sure that you're selecting a .NET Framework project template.